# Webpack bundle too big

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have recently migrated our front-end to webpack only to realize that our bundle size has gone up from ~3m to 13m+.

I have read all the advice on how to make the bundle smaller and possibly split it up, but to no avail.

webpack-bundle-analyzer (and other similar tools) proclaim my bundle is only 6m when in fact its over 13m

here is a snapshot of my config:

```
config =
  context: path.resolve __dirname, 'src'
  entry: './index.coffee'
  devtool: 'inline-source-map'
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './build'
  }
  module:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sourcemaps! Just remove

```
  devtool: 'inline-source-map'
```

because it gets activated automatically by --mode development. If you want to customize devtool you need to only include it for developement mode, either split your config or add ifs to your current single file config.